# How to extract table data from nested divs using Jsoup in Android?

Tags: android, jquery, jsoup

I am trying to extract the value of "Prev. Close" from finance.yahoo.com/q?s=[Symbol]

Here is what the HTML looks like,

```
 <div class="yui-u first yfi-start-content">
  <div class="yfi_quote_summary">
   <div id="yfi_quote_summary_data" class="rtq_table">
    <table id="table1">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th scope="row" width="48%">Prev Close:</th>
       <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">208.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th scope="row" width="48%">Open:</th>
       <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">211.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th scope="row" width="48%">Bid:</th>
       <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">N/A</td>
      </tr>      
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Here's how I tried to extract the required data.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog").get();
Elements e = doc.select("td.yfnc_tabledata1");
String close = e.get(0).text();
```

However, this gives an IndexOutOfBoundsException saying that the size of the ArrayList is 0 and hence e can't return an element.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried it. it works. Anyway add `useragent` and `referrer` to header.

Comment: That works, thank you so much!!

Comment: Good luck. I added as answer. If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Yea sure, add it as an answer and I will accept it. I'm pretty sure it will help many others too.

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the `Elements` ensure it's not empty. This way, you can avoid  `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also, as [@Hasanaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2781108/hasanaga) mentionned it, you should set `userAgent` and `referrer` headers.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6") //
     .referrer("http://finance.yahoo.com") //
     .connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog") //
     .get();

Elements e = doc.select("td.yfnc_tabledata1");
if (e.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate table cell.");
}

String close = e.get(0).text();
```